# Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range UIPickerView

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview

We made an email function with a picker view that writes its variable in a label. That works and now we added a second picker view to do the same with the articles that you should be able to send to that email address.

Basically it works but if the number of the values in each picker view is different it crashes at some point with the said error.

Here is the code:

```
import UIKit
import MessageUI

class ViewController: UIViewController, MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var techniker: UIPickerView!
    @IBOutlet weak var artikel: UIPickerView!

    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var label1: UILabel!

    var email = ["email1@email.ch", "email2@email.ch", "email3@email.ch", "email4@email.ch", "email5@email.ch"]

    var materialien = ["article", "article", "article", "article", "article", "article"]

    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        var countrows : Int
        if pickerView == artikel {
            countrows = materialien.count
        }
        else {
            countrows = materialien.count
        }
        return countrows
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        if pickerView == techniker {
            return email[row]
        }; if pickerView == artikel {
            return materialien[row]
        } else {
            return ""
        }
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        if pickerView == techniker {
            label.text = email[row]
        }; if pickerView == artikel {
            label1.text = materialien[row]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your error is in `func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int)` in all other methods you correctly check `if pickerView == artikel` or `if pickerView == techniker`, but in case of `pickerView == techniker `, you returns `materialien.count` instead of `email.count` (you return both times `materialien.count`).

Comment: ohh.... yeah.... thanks dude :D

Answer (score 0):

Your `numberOfRowsInComponent` is returning the count of `materialien` which is 6.  so if you trying to display `email[row]` which (email has 5 items) then this will be out of range.

I suspect you should change the section in `numberOfRowsInComponant` to

```
if pickerView == artikel {
   countrows = email.count
} else {
   countrows = materialien.count
}
```